# "GoogleApiClient is not connected yet." Application crash

Tags: java, android

So, I'm attempting to integrate google play services with my application and I'm failing epicly, this is my first application and it's mainly for learning purposes. The error I'm receiving is the following:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.
```

---

```
05-23 21:49:19.712: E/AndroidRuntime(14149): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-1
05-23 21:49:19.712: E/AndroidRuntime(14149): java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.
05-23 21:49:19.712: E/AndroidRuntime(14149):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.fq.a(Unknown Source)
05-23 21:49:19.712: E/AndroidRuntime(14149):    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.b.b(Unknown Source)
05-23 21:49:19.712: E/AndroidRuntime(14149):    at com.google.android.gms.games.internal.api.AchievementsImpl.unlock(Unknown Source)
05-23 21:49:19.712: E/AndroidRuntime(14149):    at com.fmeg.tapout.android.PlayServices.unlockAchievement(PlayServices.java:16)
05-23 21:49:19.712: E/AndroidRuntime(14149):    at com.fmeg.tapout.screens.GameOver.handleAchievements(GameOver.java:98)
05-23 21:49:19.712: E/AndroidRuntime(14149):    at com.fmeg.tapout.screens.GameOver.<init>(GameOver.java:36)
05-23 21:49:19.712: E/AndroidRuntime(14149):    at com.fmeg.tapout.screens.Tick.run(Play.java:85)
05-23 21:49:19.712: E/AndroidRuntime(14149):    at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

---

So I guess I'll go ahead and display the code that I have so you guys can point out where I'm going wrong.

---

```
private GoogleApiClient googleApi;

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    googleApi = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this, this, this)
    .addApi(Games.API)
    .addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
    .setGravityForPopups(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL)
    .build();

    googleApi.connect();
    ...
    initialize(new TapoutGame(impact, shareScore, googlePlay), config);

}
```

---

### ALright, so that's my main class for my android project, I'm using an interface to call my methods, but here's my methods for updating everything

```
package com.fmeg.tapout.android;

import com.fmeg.tapout.GoogleInterface;
import com.google.android.gms.games.Games;

public class PlayServices implements GoogleInterface {

    private AndroidLauncher application;

    public PlayServices(AndroidLauncher _application) {
        this.application = _application;
    }

    @Override
    public void unlockAchievement(String achievementID) {
        Games.Achievements.unlock(application.getGoogleAPI(), achievementID);
    }

    @Override
    public void achivementProgress(String achievementID, int progression) {
        Games.Achievements.increment(application.getGoogleAPI(), achievementID, progression);
    }

    @Override
    public void submitScoreToLeaderboard(String leaderboardID, int score) {
        Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(application.getGoogleAPI(), leaderboardID, score);
    }

    @Override
    public void displayLeaderboard(String leaderboardID, int request) {
        application.startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(application.getGoogleAPI(), leaderboardID), request);        
    }

}
```

---

So the error is invoked when I attempt to call unlockAchievement(String) from my core project using the following code

---

```
if(score > 200) 
    game.getGoogleInterface().unlockAchievement("idhiddenfrompublic");
```

---

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong, I'm calling connect, so it should take care of itself I would think.